# How to prevent an ASUS UX-31A from booting from the SD card reader

Tags: boot, zenbook

I intend to leave my SD card permanently in its reader slot on my [ASUS UX-31A](http://www.asus.com/us/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_ZENBOOK_UX31A/), but I could not boot normally on Windows 7 and it brings me to a black screen. How do I change the boot sequence in order to ignore the SD reader when the PC is booting?

I bought a microSD card and I want to store some data on it, but I don’t want to boot from the SD card slot.

Comment: When you power on or reboot, one of the first things that will appear (briefly), is a message with what key to press to enter BIOS settings.  You usually have just a few seconds to press that key.  There are two options.  One takes you to a menu where you select a device for that boot.  The other takes you to BIOS settings where you can change the priority sequence for future boots.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 may make it difficult to get to BIOS setup because it boots **very** quickly by default, bypassing that option. To change boot options, under the *Power Options* Control Panel applet, *Choose what the power button does*, Uncheck *Turn on fast startup* [until you've fixed your BIOS settings, then check it again]. See https://elemecca.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/unable-to-enter-bios-setup-with-windows-8/.

Hold down the <kbd>F2</kbd> key *before* the machine starts to boot to get to UEFI [BIOS} setup.

In BIOS, change the boot order so that the SD reader is at the bottom.